# Query optimization in liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created a portlet where I want to print the list of users based on some parameter. So for showing list of users I use the following code,

```
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0, UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount())%>"
        />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
        keyProperty="userId"
        modelVar="user"
    >
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="name"
            value="<%= user.getFullName() %>"
        />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="first-name"
            property="firstName"
        />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found">
```

But i don't want all the users list. I need only the list of users whose facebookId = 12345. How can  query the condition? Any suggestions please..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use DynamicQuery? You can use method: dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, start, end).

Comment: No I didn't tried. I will try and let you know. If possible suggest me some good references on dynamicQuery

Comment: I did my first steps with this article: http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-dynamic-query-api.html